# Can not find CSS file path in Django on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, css, django, apache, mod-wsgi

How to write css path on django setting file when django running on apache with mod_wsgi.
I write apache setting file as below.

```
#httpd.conf
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python3.4
WSGIPythonPath /opt/python3.4/bin/python3
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
Alias /static/ /usr/local/django/mysite/mysite/static/
```

This Alias command is for CSS path on admin site of django.
I copy static files for admin site.
[How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

I am using django version 1.7 and leading tutorial for 1.7.
Tutorial 6 is how to use static CSS and image file on django.
My django file tree is as below

```
mysite
- manage.py
+ mysite
  - settings.py
  + static
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
+ polls
  - admin.py
  - models.py
  + templates
    + polls
      - index.html
  - urls.py
  + static
    + polls
      - style.css
  - views.py
```

mysite/settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')
```

style.css is used by polls/templates/polls/views.py 
polls/templates/polls/views.py

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
```

I accessed localhost.
However, CSS file for polls does not find. (localhost/static/polls/style.css)
If I modify httpd.conf file as below.

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python3.4
WSGIPythonPath /opt/python3.4/bin/python3
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
Alias /static/ /usr/local/django/mysite/polls/static/polls/
```

It can use static file on polls application.
However, in this case, I can not find static file for admin site.
I would like to use static file on administrate site and my applications.
How can I use Static file on apache with mod_wsgi?

Comment: I think you should set `STATIC_ROOT` to a dir outside your project, adjust httpd.conf accordingly, then run `manage.py collectstatic` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic

Comment: I execute collect static.
It is work. Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like.

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/your/STATIC_ROOT/directory/

<Directory /path/to/your/STATIC_ROOT/directory>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in httpd.conf,
You should run `./manage.py collectstatic` so that all your static files + django admin static files are collected in `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

then open up your main `urls.py` and add these lines at the end

```
from settings import STATIC_ROOT
if conf.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': STATIC_ROOT}),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

add these lines to your `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'polls/static'),
)
```

and also go through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

I hope things will work now.

Comment: it's worth noting that `django.views.static.serve`, while useful, is intended for dev use only, i.e. with the Django runserver... if setting up Apache + mod_wsgi you'd normally want Apache to serve the static files instead, being faster and more secure